# Why is android restarting my activity when I call finish() on it?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that after some user interaction calls finish() on itself. From time to time it gets into a loop where when it calls finish() it finishes but immediately restarts again.

Any idea why android tries to restart my activity?

Comment: I'd help if you post part of your code/

Comment: And looking in the logcat output can be very useful as well.

Comment: happened to me. turns out, i had a 2 sec delayed method call to display the splashscreen and redirect to `MainActivity` if user is loggedIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a /facepalm error on my side. I had some logic in onPause where in some cases it would restart the activity. Hence the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This article might be of help:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Have you tried using this instead?:
Force finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(Intent, int).

```
finishActivity(int requestCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the

```
protected void onDestroy();
```

is been called,